# Jquery keypress event applied to part of document

Tags: jquery, events, bind, keypress

I have working code to catch and handle keypresses which is below

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 84 ) {
        $('svg > g > g').toggle();
    }
    else if ( event.keyCode == 90 ) {
        $('.zones').toggle();
    }
    else if ( event.keyCode == 70 ) {
        fit($('svg > g'));
    }
    else {
        var x = 1
    }
});
```

However this means that when I am typing in an input box then these shortcuts are fired which is an undesired side effect. I have tried modifying the top line so it reads

```
$('svg').keydown(function (e) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 84 ) {
        $('svg > g > g').toggle();
    }
    else if ( event.keyCode == 90 ) {
        $('.zones').toggle();
    }
    else if ( event.keyCode == 70 ) {
        fit($('svg > g'));
    }
    else {
        var x = 1
    }
});
```

This however doesn't work so how do I achieve this effect. 
I have thought of adding a variable which is modified by entering the input box and having a conditional statement but this seams a messy solution

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if any element on the page has focus and, if it does, prevent the function from firing.

http://api.jquery.com/focus/